# C++ toString outputs integer

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, tostring

I am brushing up on my C++ and I am trying to figure out why my toString function is not outputting the formatted string I defined.

The function I am referring to is: `friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Employee&);`

**Employee.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

class Employee {
  private:
    string name;
    double rate;
    double hours;
    double getPay() const;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Employee&);
  public:
    Employee(string, double);
    void setHours(double);
};

Employee::Employee(string name, double rate) {
  this->name = name;
  this->rate = rate;
  this->hours = 0;
}

void Employee::setHours(double hours) {
  this->hours = hours;
}

double Employee::getPay() const {
  double gross = this->hours * this->rate;
  double overtime = this->hours > 40 ? 
      (this->hours - 40) * (this->rate * 1.5) : 0;
    return gross + overtime;
}

// toString
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &strm, const Employee &e) {
  char buff[64];
  return strm << sprintf(buff, "Name: %s, Salary: $%.2f\n",
    e.name.c_str(), e.getPay());
}

int main (int* argc, char** argv) {
  Employee emp1("Bob", 28);
  Employee emp2("Joe", 32);
  emp1.setHours(44);
  emp2.setHours(25);
  cout << emp1 << endl;
  cout << emp2 << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::ostream` and `sprintf`... awkward combination

Comment: A suggestion would be to not mix iosteam and stdio. stdio belongs to c and it's not OOP iostream provides you with objects. Stick to iostream

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sprintf` returns:

- On success, the total number of characters written is returned. This count does not include the additional null-character automatically appended at the end of the string.
- On failure, a negative number is returned.

Under no condition it returns a string, it always returns an `int` and that is what is being printed as you request. Presumably you want this:

```
char buff[64];
sprintf(buff, "Name: %s, Salary: $%.2f\n",
  e.name.c_str(), e.getPay());
return strm << buff;
```

Although it would be better if you sticked to *streams* instead of mixing *C* and *C++* standard libraries:

```
return strm << "Name: " << e.name << ", Salary: $" << std::setprecision(2) << e.getPay() << "\n";
```

Comment: To elaborate - you should not be using `sprintf` in C++; it's unsafe and is better replaced by `stringstream`.

Comment: Damn, that was a simple fix. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

That's really not the way ostreams work. In fact if you look up sprintf you will find out you don't actually want to print its return value to strm. Instead you should be printing buf. Something like:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &strm, const Employee &e) {
  char buff[64];
  sprintf(buff, "Name: %s, Salary: $%.2f\n",
    e.name.c_str(), e.getPay());
  return strm << buff;
}
```

It is not good idea to mix sprintf and ostream but at least will make your code work.

Answer (score 1):

It's bad practice to mix C/C++ code together, just write pure c++ code,

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &strm, const Employee &e) 
{  
  strm << "Name: " << e.name << " Salary: $" << std::setprecision(2) << e.getPay();
  return strm;
}
```